# Optimize CSS Delivery - by Google

Tags: html, css, optimization, google-pagespeed

Google's suggested the Optimize CSS Delivery method according to the below document link:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#dataURI

According to the Google document I have divide the CSS into two separate CSS files.
 a) small.css  - Critical CSS
 b) common.css - Other normal CSS

Then I've place the critical CSS end of  code.

```
eg: <html>
      <head>
       <link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        content
      </body>
    <html>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css"></noscript>
```

However when view the page, that particular critical CSS(small.css) style is not applied to the HTML page. Please help me to solve this Optimize CSS Delivery method issue.

Comment: move the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css" type="text/css">` to after `<head>` tag. The external css must always be added in head.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood a couple of things:

- The `<noscript>` tag will only display contained content **if
  Javascript is disabled or not available.**
- What google is explaining is that inline CSS displays faster than CSS
  in external files.

inline CSS looks like:

```
 <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
 </head>
```

while external files with CSS are included like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Now to answer your question, your CSS is not displayed because it is contained in the noscript tag. Here is the correct way to do it:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css" type="text/css">
   <link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
<html>
```

Or if you are following googles recommendation:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
   //Copy content of small.css here
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    //content with inline styling
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: I should add that what Google is stating is that you should _not_ put an external CSS file in the head (even if you inline "small.css"). Any external CSS file found will cause the renderer to block. Unfortunately, the only way around this is to use JS to lazy-load the CSS file with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the noscript tag ? Its only for identifying if the JavaScript is not present , so the css will not be loaded .

Also , CSS can be on the top of the code , need not be below . Try only keeping the js code below.